# Почему блок при маленьком разрешении экрана прилип к потолку и не отображаются загаловки?

Tags: html, css

Почему блок при уменьшенном разрешении экрана прилипает к верху и не отображаются заголовки, в то время, когда я выставляю разрешение 768х1024, то все отображается и не прилипает. Как сделать так, чтобы на минимальном разрешении все отображалось хорошо?

Код jsfiddle.net/64otgzdk/

Сайт ilyin1ib.beget.tech

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Высота у родителя фиксированная стоит?

Comment: да, но я сменил в медиа-запросах на auto

Comment: Я так понял вы уже исправили? На сайте все нормально отображается.